# Email field validation in Coldfusion

Tags: forms, validation, coldfusion, email-validation

I'm a very new to Coldfusion scripting. I need to validate an Email field on a form, so that the Email field accepts "...@waldorf.edu" email address from prospective applicants ONLY. All other email addresses should be an error. I have this code right now, but it doesn't validate the domain unfortunately.

```
<tr bgcolor="##ffffff">
      <td   valign="top" class="style13"><strong>Email</strong><br />
      <font size="2">(Must be Waldorf faculty member. <strong>Use "waldorf.edu" email address only.)</strong></font></td>
      <td  valign="top"><font color="##FF0000">*</font>
      <cfinput type="text" Name="email" Message="Please input a valid Waldorf Email Address, ex.: you@waldorf.edu." validate="email" required="yes"  value="#appinfo.email#" size="40">  </td>
    </tr>
```

Thank you for your help!
Controller:

```
<cfcomponent name="fellowsapp" output="false">
 <cfscript>
     function init(fw) { variables.fw = fw; }
</cfscript>  

<cffunction name="validate" access="public" returntype="array" output="false">
    <cfargument name="rc" type="struct" />
    <cfargument name="form" type="struct" />        
    <cfset var errors = arrayNew(1) />
    <cfset var thisError = structNew() />
<!--- Email --->
    <cfif form.Email eq ''>
        <cfset thisError.field = "Email" />
        <cfset thisError.type = "error" />
        <cfset thisError.message = "Email is required" />
        <cfset arrayAppend(errors,duplicate(thisError)) />
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Where did you write your validation at?

Comment: The above code is in a View. in a Controller I have this code that i added to the above code below.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but since you mentioned being new to CF ... unless you are maintaining legacy code, use of CF UI controls is [generally discouraged these days](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/oi-you-bloody-wankers-stop-using.html). The main reasons being they use outdated JS libraries and are notoriously quirky and difficult to customize.

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is to only allow @waldorf.edu email addresses, simply take away the option for the user to enter that part of the address.  Make it obvious to the user.  Something like this:

```
<cfinput name="email" 
required="yes"
message = "Please enter an email address"
>@waldorf.edu
```

If you want to enhance this on the form page, you can add some javascript that strips away the @character and everything after it.

In your controller, use a regular expression to ensure that the submitted value contains only characters that are valid for @waldorf.edu email addresses.